# What site is good for GitHub questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, github

Not [Git](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git), but [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)... single or multiple repositories, GitHub-style documentation, etc.

Comment: Depends on what you're asking

Comment: suppose it's a question about github-style docs, or repository organization.

Comment: [This site](https://github.com/contact) would be perfect.

Comment: @JackManey - Perhaps your comment was only intended to be funny, but in all seriousness, there are legitimate questions to ask about GitHub best practices that I would prefer to have answered by fellow SO-ers (SE-ers) as opposed to someone in GitHub's customer support department.

Comment: @MarkHarrison, While Quora has an undue hatred within SE community, objectively speaking it's a [good site for GitHub](https://www.quora.com/GitHub) questions.

Comment: I'm going to try for a Git.SE beta

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally, Stack Overflow is fine, but as random pointed out in his comment, it depends what is being asked:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github

GitHub is certainly a tool commonly used by programmers, per the FAQ. I like to think one of the best ways to decide what to ask is to first observe what is being asked and answered well by the community.

(This should also explain why things that are popular for the wrong reasons, that are opinion pieces rather than science, are deeply problematic at SE.)

Since you specified

> suppose it's a question about github-style docs, or repository organization

That implies it could be opinion-y, or a bit too specific to GitHub's own peculiarities. Overall though GitHub is so *overwhelmingly* a programmer site that some opinion and/or specificity to GitHub is likely to be OK.

Comment: What about programmers.SE? Why would stackoverflow be more appropriate instead of programmers.SE?

Comment: Jeff, github is not a [tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_tool), it is a [service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service). Is it not?

Comment: Nathaniel Ford [makes the point](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225906/188599) that a SaaS will `change often and in an unversioned manner: ` which will render the answer incorrect over time: `Future users of S.O. will find that the information quickly becomes bad` ... [GH] `doesn't get to decide to offload their forum here` repeating that `and the answer is now wrong, so even though it was well received it is now not useful`.

Comment: I have a question about billing that I cannot find answered anywhere. I assume this does not fit StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6):

And it turns out the GitHub guys concur with Jeff! From [the announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/github/TbbbBkAm-jk) where they shut down their Google Groups group:

> After three glorious years, we're shutting down this Google Group next
>   Monday, May 9th, 2011.
>
> You can always contact Official GitHub Support by emailing
>   sup...@github.com or visiting https://github.com/contact
>
> As for unofficial help, we recommend Stack Overflow:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github

Comment: There're many projects/sites that offload their support to SO. This does not automatically make those threads on-topic.....

Comment: @Pacerier Nathaniel Ford's [https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225906/188599](point) aggrees with yours: `doesn't get to decide to offload their forum here`. and says the web service `change often and in an unversioned manner` ... `the information quickly becomes bad`

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to the Web interface, then certainly [WebApps.SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/). WebApps.SE deals explicitly with web applications as accessed by users of the application. If you're referring to [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), or SSH, as end user applications on your own system that merely access [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) servers then certainly [Super User](http://www.superuser.com). If you're referring to an API, or integration with GitHub by way of something like [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) -- then probably [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). And, lastly, if you want to get away from them and run your own clone or start a centralized Git endpoint then perhaps [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) which deals with server administration.

Stack Exchange has a high learning curve. To figure this kind of stuff out it usually takes a lot of use. If you ask in the wrong place and the moderators don't like the question and catch it within an arbitrary time frame, your questions may be migrated. That's no problem. Don't forget you can always read the specific site's FAQ by clicking `FAQ` at the bottom of the screen. The FAQ will tell you what is on-topic and not on-topic. As a last resort, you can always send a quick e-mail to team@stackoverflow.com and ask them for an authoritative decree.

As of now there are only [92 sites on the Stack Exchange network to choose from.](https://stackexchange.com/sites) It's probably worth it to just take a day out and read all of their `/faq`s.

Comment: i would say don't bother e-mailing team@stack. there is no such thing as an 'authoritative decree' for this type of thing. even if whoever reads that email says yes, the community can vote to close or flag to migrate.

Comment: @Evan, The FAQ does not tell you what is on-topic and what's not. What it does is provide **vague** guidelines that may determine what's on-topic and what's not. Which is exactly why you stated SE "has a high learning curve", because [tacit rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_knowledge) are not codified.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the [GitHub support refers](https://support.github.com/contact) to the [GitHub Community Forum](https://github.community/):

> Please feel free to ask questions and share ideas with GitHub experts in the [GitHub Community Forum](https://github.community/).